# Optional variable in a terraform block

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want to deploy a **`azurerm_linux_function_app`** and depending on the access restrictions I will need a restriction from a VNET and other times I will need an IP address restriction.
The code is:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                = var.function_app_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = "northeurope"
    
  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account_name
  service_plan_id            = var.service_plan_id
    
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  site_config {
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = var.enable_restriction == true ? [1] : []
        content {
          virtual_network_subnet_id = var.subnet_id
          ip_address                = var.ip_address
        }
    }

    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.8"
    }
  }
}
```

In the block called "ip_restriction" is where I want to have both variables, but sometimes I will want the VNET id and other times the IP address.

Comment: What is the condition under which you would want subnet id or IP address?

Comment: I want to set an access restriction for function apps, and depending the function app, we will set a restriction from a subnet or from an IP address. The problem is that I need to define both variables on ip_restriction block, and if both are defined I will need to set a value for both, and that will not work.

Comment: I understand that, but under which conditions would you use one or the other? I know how to write the syntax, I just need the tie-breaker condition. Also, isn't `ip_restriction` a list?

Comment: I don´t understand you, sorry.  Also "ip_restriction" is a block (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.11.0/docs/resources/linux_function_app#:~:text=An-,ip_restriction,-block%20supports%20the)

Comment: Ok, so when would `virtual_network_subnet_id` be set and when would you set `ip_address`? What needs to happen in order to use one or the other? Some other variable needs to have a value? Something inside of the resource itself should happen to choose one or the other? `ip_restriction` block is a list of objects btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you have 2 dynamic blocks for each of the cases?  Only 1 of these variables will be set, is that right?

```
 resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                = var.function_app_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = "northeurope"

  storage_account_name       = var.storage_account_name
  service_plan_id            = var.service_plan_id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  site_config {
    dynamic "ip_restriction"{
      for_each = var.enable_restriction == true && var.subnet_id != "" ? [1] : []
      content {
        virtual_network_subnet_id = var.subnet_id
      }
    }
    dynamic "ip_restriction"{
      for_each = var.enable_restriction == true && var.ip_address != "" ? [1] : []
      content {
        ip_address                = var.ip_address
      }
    }
    application_stack {
      python_version = "3.8"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That will not work because the `subnet_id` and `ip_address` most probably are not boolean values.

Comment: Could he set the condition on the ternary operator to the default value of the variable ("")?  It sounds like these variables need defaults as they are not set if the other is set.  I edited the answer just now to account for that.

Comment: It depends on how many blocks of `ip_restriction` can be defined. This might work if more than one is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

For arguments inside `resource` blocks and the blocks nested inside them like `ip_restriction` here, assigning the value `null` to the argument is exactly equivalent to omitting it entirely: from the provider's perspective it cannot tell the difference because the Terraform language automatically sends `null` to represent "not set" when it sends the configuration to the provider.

Therefore if you make sure both of your variables will be `null` when you want them to be unset then you'll get the right behavior essentially "for free". `null` is the correct way to represent the absense of a value in Terraform; an empty string is not suitable to represent "unset" because an empty string is a valid value for some arguments.

For example:

```
variable "subnet_id" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

variable "ip_address" {
  type    = string
  default = null
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  # ...

  site_config {
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = var.enable_restriction == true ? [1] : []
      content {
        # If either variable is null then the provider will
        # treat it as if unset.
        virtual_network_subnet_id = var.subnet_id
        ip_address                = var.ip_address
      }
    }

    # ...
  }
}
```

If you only use the subnet ID and the IP address as part of the IP restriction and don't need them in any other context, an idiomatic way to model this would be to make `ip_restriction` be a single input variable of an object type and use its presence to decide whether to include the `ip_restriction` block:

```
variable "ip_restriction" {
  type = object({
    subnet_id  = optional(string)
    ip_address = optional(string)
  })
  default = null
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  # ...

  site_config {
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = var.ip_restriction[*]
      content {
        virtual_network_subnet_id = ip_restriction.value.subnet_id
        ip_address                = ip_restriction.value.ip_address
      }
    }

    # ...
  }
}
```

This structure tends to make it clearer how these different values are all related to one another, and avoids the nonsensical situation of setting either `subnet_id` or `ip_address` when the `ip_restriction` block isn't enabled at all: it isn't possible for the entire object to be null while the attributes inside are non-null.